# Issue with saving, loading from cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to make a cookie that if it exists it loads from it into a variable. the cookie only stores an int. then it also saves to a cookie during the game. here's what I have tried:

```
//saving

document.cookie = "savedLevels=;" + level;


//loading

if ( document.cookie.indexOf("savedLevels") >= 0 ) {
    currentHighestLevel = getCookie("savedLevels");
    for ( var i = 0; i < currentHighestLevel; i++ ) {
        if ( currentHighestLevel >= i ) {
            ( level + i + Locked ) = false;
        alert("Worked!" + i);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a variable named "level"+i+"Locked"? If so, use an array for goodness' sake!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very specific syntax error that happened to the user

Comment: If you're using a Cookie to store a value, I'd recommend using a Session scope instead, otherwise sensitive values could be viewed, and changed by the user. Languages such as PHP, ColdFusion, ASP (to name a few) can provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

your semicolon is in the wrong place

```
document.cookie = "savedLevels=" + level;
```